# Hypotheses Testing and Calculating Statistical Significance on Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python, structural-change

I'm trying to compare the growth (annual change) in average house price in the UK before and after the EU referendum.  I want to test whether the decline in growth (since the referendum) is statistically significant or just by chance. I have split the growth in two data sets, one for before the referendum and one for after. In case it helps to answer my problem, I am trying to model the entire statistical problem in Python.

My null hypothesis is that there is no significant difference between the growth. So far I have generated permuted samples which takes all the data (growth) points before and after the referendum, put them in two arrays of growth data points (with the same length as the initial data), and then calculated the differences of the means for every replicated pair (repeated this 100,000 times using a defined function in Python). This gives me a large array of differences in the means of all replicated pairs. This allows me to generate a p-value of the probability that I will get a difference in the means as high as observed (or more), suggesting the null hypothesis can be rejected (based on a low p-value).

My concern is that I am permuting this data from different time periods and I'm not sure whether that's a reasonable way to model time series data as in the samples one could get a growth of -10% one month and +5% the next month and vice versa. I have also tested the growth sets for normality (using D’Agostino and Jarque-Bera tests) and they are not normally distributed so I have not resampled them using a normal distribution with a given mean and standard deviation (of the original data) and tried to compare the different means of them.

I really would like to find a way to test if the change in growth since the referendum is statistically significant, one way or another. I would also like to know that if my method of calculating whether the difference between the two means is significant, is completely inaccurate and what method(s) would be useful for me to try to model in Python.

Comment: I wouldn't approach this problem like this. What I would do is: 1) Test for structural changes. If there is a difference in the mean (permanent) it should find a structural change on the (or around) the date of the referendum. Therefore, I advice you to read on structural changes. Another thing I will do is add a dummy variable with 0 before the referendum and 1 after. I will then run a regression yt = b1D + et, where D is the dummy for the referendum. If the t-statistic is significant then, this means that knowing if the data is before matters (keep in mind that you must remove trend first).

Comment: Thanks I'll have a read on structural changes and see how I can apply that to my problem. But why would the way I approached it not be advised?